# spark column to rows

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a single column dataframe, and I want to convert it to a single row dataframe.

```
ColumnA
4
8
4

column1 column2 column3
4.               8.             4
```

this is in a streaming context.i have searched and searched but I have not found a way to do this.

Comment: try searching for `pivot` and you will get a lot of information on how to do that

Comment: You have only three data to transform? Can you explain a bit more.

Comment: So my understanding of pivoting involves grouping. I do not want to group in anyway. I want to literally take a long single column dataframe and "transpose" it to being a wide single row dataframe.  I'm trying to get around a limitation in spark. I have the need to filter and calculate data from a second streaming dataframe. The hard part is there is no key to match them. Every row in this long dataframe is a complex embeded structure from jason format. If I can have the second dataframe to have the first then I can use any of the spark API's. You can't use spark apis in UDF or map functions.